# Unable to click NavigationBarItems after dynamically closing sheet bug or not?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have NavigationView with NavigationBarItems button. Button invokes a sheet which I can normally close by dragging down and open again by clicking a button.

Problem: if I exit a panel with a button click inside a sheet, I can no longer click buttons on the panel.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
                .navigationBarTitle("Mapp")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: showSheetFunc) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus").padding(5)
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                    SheetView(showSheet: self.$showSheet)
            }
        }

    }

    private func showSheetFunc() {
        self.showSheet = true
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showSheet = false}) {
            Text("Close Me")
        }
    }
}
```

I have made a video to illustrate the problem. At the end, when I click the button, nothing happens.

https://streamable.com/tza9v4

Comment: Bug... as I recall it was already reported somewhere around here - you can also submit feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more padding to your button image like :

```
Image(systemName: "plus").padding(20)
```